# Pygame Localhost Link

Tags: python, pygame, pygbag

I finally finished creating my game in pygame, but when I use pygbag command and usethe local host link, it asks to press start and all that, but when i reach the final step it just shows a black screen and I don't know why, and this makes it a huge struggle to upload my game on itch.io, So i hope anyone knows a fix. Here's the code:

'

```
import asyncio
import pygame
import os

pygame.font.init() #Importing the pygame font library
pygame.mixer.init() #Imports the pygame sound library

WIDTH, HEIGHT = 1200, 800
WIN = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))  # dimensions of window
pygame.display.set_caption("Trash Game")  # Name of window
CYANCOLOR = (125, 255, 255)  # Color of screen
WHITECOLOR = (255, 255, 255)
BLACKCOLOR = (0, 0, 0)
REDCOLOR = (255, 0, 0)
YELLOWCOLOR = (255, 255, 0)

Health_font = pygame.font.SysFont('comicsans', 60)
Winner_Font = pygame.font.SysFont('comicsans', 100)

Border = pygame.Rect(WIDTH//2, 0, 10, HEIGHT)  # Divides screen into two halves

Player_HIT_Sound = pygame.mixer.Sound(os.path.join('Assets', 'Grenade+1.mp3')) #Creating sounds for the game
Player_SHOOT_Sound = pygame.mixer.Sound(os.path.join('Assets', 'Gun+Silencer.mp3'))

FPS = 60  # How often our screen refreshes per second
Bullet_Speed = 9
Bullet_Limit = 4

Yellow_HIT = pygame.USEREVENT+1 #We can check if the ship was hit by a bullet
Red_HIT = pygame.USEREVENT+2

YellowSpaceship_Shape = pygame.image.load(os.path.join('Assets', 'spaceship_yellow.png'))  # This command allows us to access the things inside the assets folder, so we can use our drawings
YellowSpaceship = pygame.transform.rotate(pygame.transform.scale(YellowSpaceship_Shape, (80, 60)),90)  # We created anew thing so that we can make the original image smaller, by scaling it down, and the other command lets us rotate the image
RedSpaceship_Shape = pygame.image.load(os.path.join('Assets', 'spaceship_red.png'))  # This command allows us to
RedSpaceship = pygame.transform.rotate(pygame.transform.scale(RedSpaceship_Shape, (80, 60)),270)  # We created anew thing so that we can make an enemy spaceship, and we made it 270 degrees because we want to fight our main spaceship

Background = pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load(os.path.join('Assets', 'space.png')), (WIDTH, HEIGHT)) #We are making the background of the game a picture form the assets folder

def draw_window(red, yellow, red_bullets, yellow_bullets, red_lives, yellow_lives):  # This gives the things that we want our window to have like color, background, projectiles and characters
    WIN.blit(Background, (0, 0))
    pygame.draw.rect(WIN, BLACKCOLOR, Border)  # Draws border on screen

    red_lives_text = Health_font.render("LIVES: " + str(red_lives), 1, WHITECOLOR) #We use the font initialized earlier, and we take the amount of lives of the ship and convert that into a string
    yellow_lives_text = Health_font.render("LIVES: " + str(yellow_lives), 1, WHITECOLOR) #We use the font initialized earlier, and we take the amount of lives of the ship and convert that into a string
    WIN.blit(red_lives_text, (WIDTH-red_lives_text.get_width() - 10, 50)) #Drawing the red and yellow health on the screen
    WIN.blit(yellow_lives_text, (10, 50))

    WIN.blit(YellowSpaceship, (yellow.x, yellow.y))  # You use blit when you want to draw something/surface onthe screen
    WIN.blit(RedSpaceship, (red.x, red.y))

    for bullet in yellow_bullets:
        pygame.draw.rect(WIN, YELLOWCOLOR, bullet) #Drawing in the WINDOW a bullet with color yellow, as we already created the dimensions of the bullet

    for bullet in red_bullets:
        pygame.draw.rect(WIN, REDCOLOR, bullet) #Drawing int the WINDOW a bullet with the color red, as we already created the dimensions of the bullet

    pygame.display.update()


def yellow_movement(key_pressed, yellow):  # checks for movement of yellow ship
    if key_pressed[pygame.K_a] and yellow.x-4 > 0:  # This checks if the button that was pressed was "a" and moves us left, and makes sure we aren't outside the screen
        yellow.x -= 6

    if key_pressed[pygame.K_d] and yellow.x+4+yellow.width < Border.x:  # This checks if the button that was pressed was "d" and moves us right
        yellow.x += 6

    if key_pressed[pygame.K_w] and yellow.y-4 > 0:  # This checks if the button that was pressed was "w" and moves us up
        yellow.y -= 6

    if key_pressed[pygame.K_s] and yellow.y+4+yellow.height < HEIGHT:  # This checks if the button that was pressed was "a"
        yellow.y += 6


def red_movement(key_pressed, red):  # checks for movement of red ship
    if key_pressed[pygame.K_LEFT] and red.x-4 > Border.x + Border.width:  # This checks if the button that was pressed was "left arrow" and moves us left
        red.x -= 6

    if key_pressed[pygame.K_RIGHT] and red.x+4+red.width < WIDTH:  # This checks if the button that was pressed was "right arrow" and moves us right
        red.x += 6

    if key_pressed[pygame.K_UP] and red.y-4 > 0:  # This checks if the button that was pressed was "up arrow" and moves us up
        red.y -= 6

    if key_pressed[pygame.K_DOWN] and red.y+4+red.height < HEIGHT:  # This checks if the button that was pressed was "down arrow" and moves down
        red.y += 6

def bullets_handling(yellow_bullets, red_bullets, yellow, red): #We want to check if the bullets collided with our spaceships
    for bullet in yellow_bullets: #This is if a yellow bullet was shot
        bullet.x+=Bullet_Speed
        if red.colliderect(bullet): #This tells us that if the bullet collided with the red rocket
            pygame.event.post(pygame.event.Event(Red_HIT)) #This creates an event that says the red ship was hit
            yellow_bullets.remove(bullet) #This removes the bullet when it collides with the red ship
        elif bullet.x > WIDTH:
            yellow_bullets.remove(bullet) #This makes so if the bullet leaves the screen we will destroy the bullet

    for bullet in red_bullets: #This is if a red bullet was shot
        bullet.x-=Bullet_Speed
        if yellow.colliderect(bullet): #This tells us that if the bullet collided with the yellow rocket
            pygame.event.post(pygame.event.Event(Yellow_HIT)) #This creates an event that says the yellow ship was hit
            red_bullets.remove(bullet) #This removes a bullet from the red_bullets list when it collides with the yellow ship
        elif bullet.x < 0:
            red_bullets.remove(bullet) #This makes so if the bullet leaves the screen we will destroy the bullet

def winner(text):
    draw_text = Winner_Font.render(text, 1, WHITECOLOR)
    WIN.blit(draw_text, (WIDTH//2 - draw_text.get_width()//2, HEIGHT//2 - draw_text.get_height()//2)) #Putting the winner text based on the winner
    pygame.display.update() #Updates the screen to show the winner
    pygame.time.delay(7000) #We will show the winner of the game for 7 seconds

async def main():
    red = pygame.Rect(700, 300, 80, 60)  # represents the yellow position / hit box
    yellow = pygame.Rect(100, 300, 80, 60)
    yellow_bullets= [] #List of yellow bullets
    red_bullets = [] #List of red bullets
    yellow_lives = 10
    red_lives = 10
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    run = True  # Makes it so our program runs infinitely, unless otherwise said
    while run:
        clock.tick(FPS)  # Applies the fps of the game, every tick in real-life
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False
                pygame.quit()

            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LSHIFT and len(yellow_bullets) < Bullet_Limit: #Checks if the amount of bullet used is more than the max
                    bullet=pygame.Rect(yellow.x + yellow.width, yellow.y + yellow.height//2, 16, 8) # Creating a bullet variable with its spawn position and size
                    yellow_bullets.append(bullet) #We put this bullet in the yellow bullet list
                    Player_SHOOT_Sound.play()

                if event.key == pygame.K_RSHIFT and len(red_bullets) < Bullet_Limit:
                    bullet = pygame.Rect(red.x + red.width, red.y + red.height//2, 16,8)  # Creating a bullet variable with its spawn position and size
                    red_bullets.append(bullet)  # We put this bullet in the red bullet list
                    Player_SHOOT_Sound.play()

            if event.type == Yellow_HIT: #If the yellow ship gets hit we will subtract a life
                yellow_lives -= 1
                Player_HIT_Sound.play()

            if event.type == Red_HIT: #If the red ship gets hit we will subtract a life
                red_lives -= 1
                Player_HIT_Sound.play()

        winner_text = "" #Creating a variable for the text that will play when someone wins
        if yellow_lives <= 0:
            winner_text = "Player Red Wins!!"

        if red_lives <= 0:
            winner_text = "Player Yellow Wins!!"

        if winner_text != "":
            winner(winner_text) #This means that when someone wins, the text parameter that we defined up there will be equal to the winner_text, amd then that text will be shown
            break

        key_pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()  # This is a variable that records the button we just pressed, and is 1 of two ways to see the button we just pressed
        yellow_movement(key_pressed, yellow)
        red_movement(key_pressed, red)

        bullets_handling(yellow_bullets, red_bullets, yellow, red) #Call the function that shoots the bullets

        draw_window(red, yellow, red_bullets, yellow_bullets, red_lives, yellow_lives)  # call the function that give the window its color and characters

        await asyncio.sleep(0)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

I followed a lot of tutorials so I don't why this doesn't work

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Is there any warning when you run the pygbag debugger? With pygbag running try adding "/#debug" right after the url address on browser.